# how to add a button in inner HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, innerhtml

I'm trying to make my first website.
I wanted to add a button under the text, which is displayed after clicking on the first position from my list. I want to put a button that will let you go back to the start list.

Can somebody help me? :)

This is my code

```
<script>


  function choseMasage() {
      let ul = document.querySelector("ul");
      ul.innerHTML = "My Lomilomi is a concept of Hawaiian massage techniques and my intuition. It is a mixture of my intentions and your needs. Massage is the best you can get and I can offer,it is a basic human need. Touch can also heil. <br> Before beginning a massage, you can prepare yourself and your mind for my touch, which deeply and soothingly loosens your body. I will treat you with understanding and protection. Amazing massage with hot organic coconut oil, starting its soothing effect through the skin, stimulating all tissues, will cleanse the mind and relax your soul. Everybody is different, every body is different, and because of that, every massage is also unique and exceptional. I will concentrate on all parts of your body,  you will be touched the way you want it. Let me give you a little happiness.<br>The massage lasts from one to two hours, you can chose how long you need to feel the pleasure of relaxation. Body and soul need time and you will get it. Fall in love with taking care of yourself, and reserve a termin.<br> <button>back</button>"
      
    }
    
function choseMasage2() {
  let ul = document.querySelector("ul");
  ul.innerHTML = "<ul> <li>text 2</li></ul>"

}
    let choseButton = document.querySelector("button.one");
    choseButton.addEventListener("click", choseMasage);

    let choseButton2 = document.querySelector("button.two");
    choseButton2.addEventListener("click", choseMasage2);
  

  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You should not use `innerHTML` to add elements. It is slow as the DOM needs to be prepared and will cause security issues (XSS). Either use `createElement` or `insertAdjacentHTML`. It might be easier to just use an anchor that will move you pack to an element with a certain ID:

Answer (score 0):

I have augmented *your* code a little. I didn't follow best practices though. So take it step by step and improve what you can.

```js
function choseMasage() {
  return "My Lomilomi is a concept of Hawaiian massage techniques and my intuition. It is a mixture of my intentions and your needs. Massage is the best you can get and I can offer,it is a basic human need. Touch can also heil. <br> Before beginning a massage, you little happiness.<br>The massage lasts from one to two hours, you can chose how long you need to feel the pleasure of relaxation. Body and soul need time and you will get it. Fall in love with taking care of yourself, and reserve a termin.<br> "
}

function choseMasage2() {
  return "human need. Touch can also heil. <br> Before beginning a massage, you little happiness.<br>The massage lasts from one to two hours, you can chose how long you need to feel the pleasure of relaxation. Body and soul need time";
}

function show_article(func) {
  var html = func();
  content.innerHTML = html;
  content.style.display = 'block'
  ul.style.display = 'none'
  backButton.style.display = 'block'
}

function show_list() {
  content.style.display = 'none'
  ul.style.display = 'block'
  backButton.style.display = 'none'
}

let ul = document.querySelector(".list");
let content = document.querySelector(".content");

let choseButton = document.querySelector("button.one");
choseButton.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
  show_article(choseMasage)
});

let choseButton2 = document.querySelector("button.two");
choseButton2.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
  show_article(choseMasage2)
});

let backButton = document.querySelector("button.back");
backButton.addEventListener("click", show_list);
```

```css
.back,
.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="one">one</button>
<button class="two">two</button>

<ul class="list">
  <li>original</li>
  <li>list</li>
</ul>

<div class="content"></div>

<button class="back">back</button>
```

Comment: thanks, it helped but exactly I did not want to clear my list after clicking on the backButton, my idea was that when I click on the button the list will be back.

Comment: i don't understand that all I am sorry
I deleted what you posted the first time
so all my code not working 
sooo, and ps
´function choseMasage2() {
  return "human need. Touch can also heil. <br> Before beginning a massage, you little happiness.<br>The massage lasts from one to two hours, you can chose how long you need to feel the pleasure of relaxation. Body and soul need time";
}
´
did you be so afraid that you could not continue something?

Comment: The snippet works as I understood your description and code you provided.